# Angular Routing not working, the URL changes but the page doesn't load correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angular-routing

Below is my file structure, please let me know what I am doing wrong that my routing is not working:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appNakul">
<head>
    <title> Nakul Chawla</title>
    <!--<base href="App/"/>-->
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>


<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#/">Default Route</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/resume">Resume Route</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/home">Home Route</a></li>

</ul>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="shared/common.js"></script>
<script src="appNakul.js"></script>

<script src="shared/indexCtrl.js"></script>

<script src="home/homeCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="resume/resumeCtrl.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**appNakul.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('appNakul', ['ngRoute' ])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/home', {
                title: 'Home',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
            })
                .when('/resume', {
                    title: 'Resume',
                    templateUrl: 'resume.html',
                    controller: 'resumeCtrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/home'
                });
            // $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
        })
        .run(function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event,currentRoute,previousRoute) {
                document.title = currentRoute.title;
            });
        });
});
```

apart from this I have a resume folder and a home folder that have basic html layouts and Ctrl files that both look like below:

**resumeCtrl.js**

```
(function(){
   'use strict';
    angular.module('appNakul').controller('resumeCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','$routeParams','$route', function($scope,$rootScope,$routeParams,$route){

    }]);

});
```

The URL that gets created is :
`../App/index.html#/home`, but the URL that is actually loading the content is `..App/home/home.html`

[image]

Comment: Can you show the folder/file structure of your app?

Comment: I have added it as an image.

Comment: Nothing is jumping out as being wrong with your set-up, especially if the /home route isn't loading correctly either. Does the console output an error?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module appNakul due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'appNakul' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument`

Comment: I have instantiated my app in common.js like below: `(function(){
    var appNakul = angular.module('appNakul');

});`

Comment: As the error says, to register a module you must specify dependencies as the second argument. If none, you still have to pass an empty array. `(function(){ var appNakul = angular.module('appNakul', []); });`

Comment: still doesn't work. I think the problem is in the way I have defined my app structure, but I am not able to figure out how.

Comment: I've figured it out and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New answer**
In your `appNakul.js` you are instantiating the module in an anonymous function. Only thing is, you're not calling the function!
Change it to this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('appNakul', ['ngRoute' ])
    // Truncated
})();
```

And you should be good to go.

**Old but still relevant answer**
Looks like your `templateUrl` for the route is incorrect.
You said you have a resume and a home folder, the url should be in the resume folder then.

```
.when('/resume', {
    title: 'Resume',
    templateUrl: 'resume/resume.html',
    controller: 'resumeCtrl'
})
```

Comment: even then my home route looks correct, even the home isn't working.

Comment: this worked. Thanks a lot. I had made a couple of other mistakes, but the inherent problem was that I wasn't calling the anonymous function. Is this a good way to code? Just asking, writing anonymous functions for js files, or shall I change my ways?

Comment: All comes down to either personal preference or business preference. I'm certainly not in a position to say one way is better than the other however, I do believe that anonymous functions are suggested when writing AngularJS code. Keeping everything off Window and all that.